# Should an edit of a comment be sent through POST or PUT?

Tags: http, rest, architecture

I have the following URI: `Posts/{postId}/Comments/{commentId}`
I would like to enable users to edit a comment through my API, should the edit be done with POST or PUT?
One one hand, POST updates the contents of a resource so that makes sense but on the other hand PUT replaces it with a new one. So if I understand correctly with POST I need to send only what needs to be updates and with PUT I send the whole resource.
Usually in edit forms, the whole resource is loaded anyway so what's the point of using POST?
If I take one approach or the other, what are the differences?

Comment: To say `POST updates the contents of a resource` is over constraining the use of POST.   See `http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-12#section-7.5`  for the most up to date definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have read (in [*RESTful Web Services*, published by O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260)), it seems clear that you should use `PUT` to update an existing comment.

- `PUT` is meant to be used for updating as well as creating a resource.
- `POST` can also be used for creating a resource. The difference here is that when `POST`ing, you don't need to know the exact URI of the resource to be created. (The service will report the new resource's URI in its response.)
- `POST` is appropriate for partial updates, or when appending information to a resource; `PUT` is appropriate for a full update (replacement) of a resource.
- When updating, you *can* send partial updates, but you should make sure that these are idempotent; ie. if you send the same update more than once, the update will always have the same effect. Don't send an update such as "Increase *n* by 1"; instead, send an update such as "Set *n* to 5."

Thus, my suggestion for your case are as follows:

- Use `POST` to `/Posts/{postId}/Comments` to create a new comment, since the client doesn't know the `{commentId}` in advance.
- Use `PUT` `/Posts/{postId}/Comments/{commentId}` to completely update a comment (or perhaps `POST` when appending text to it).

Answer (score 1):

see here:
[PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)